# Is there a css selector for knowing if a block is right or below?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-float

I have two blocks with float: left so the display depends on the page width :

```
[Block A] [Block B]
```

or

```
[Block A]
[Block B]
```

Is there a css selector for distinguishing those two cases? For instance it could be

```
.block:below { margin-left: 20px; }
```

Comment: Maybe you wanted to say _"right or below" or "left or above"_. What's the point of achieving such a thing? Look into media-queries if you are targeting reponsivenes this way

Comment: what if I want to display a separation line if they are inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no CSS selectors for any of the multitude of possible positions a floating element may be in relative to other floats and the rest of the layout. Mostly because there are no CSS selectors that match elements based on layout.

If the positions of these floating elements depend on the page width, use a media query instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no any selector but **I'm not sure** until sure you can use below code

```
if($('.className').css('display') == 'block')
{
// do something
}else if($('.className').css('display') == 'inline-block'){
     //do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that by using media queries like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:460px){
       .block{ margin-right: 20px; }
}
```

This way the code only applies when the screen is narrower than 460px, which makes it more controllable.